# Xcode 5 Interface Builder-designed light text appearing regular weight on iOS 6

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, interface-builder, uilabel

I've built a view in Interface Builder on Xcode 5:

[image]

On iOS 7 devices, this runs perfectly (displays exactly as seen on IB). The selected UILabel's font is Helvetica Neue Thin. However, when I try it on iOS 6.1, my font renders improperly:

[image]

I'm aware of the iOS 7 SDK's text view's `selectable = NO` bug which doesn't set the text properly, but my views are UILabels, not UITextViews.

How can I make my UILabels display properly on iOS 6 too?

Comment: Is Helvetica Neue Thin available in iOS 6? http://www.ios6-fonts.com I think you need to use light or ultra light.

Comment: I wasn't aware of Thin is not available in iOS 6. Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Done, I assume that solved your situation?

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. Changing the font worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helvetica Neue Thin is not available in iOS6

[iOS 6 Fonts](http://ios6-fonts.com)

You should use light or ultra light.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that Helvetica Neue Thin doesn't exist in iOS6 - thin was introduced in iOS7. You will either need to find another comparable font, or reduce the font size so that it fits into your allocated space under iOS6.